# Цикл for (JS), вывести информация в консоль

Tags: javascript, for

```
let weeks = [
  'Понедельник',
  'Вторник',
  'Среда',
  'Четверг',
  'Пятница'
  'Суббота'
  'Воскресенье'
];
```

Как циклом "for" вывести в консоль каждый день недели по порядку?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for - в теле цикла делаете console.log.

Comment: `for (let i of weeks) console.log(i)`

Answer (score 2):

У вас проблема в массиве, не везде поставили запятые

Можно так:

```js
let weeks = [
  'Понедельник',
  'Вторник',
  'Среда',
  'Четверг',
  'Пятница',
  'Суббота',
  'Воскресенье',
];

for (let i = 0; i < weeks.length; i++) {
  console.log(weeks[i])
}
```

Comment: А у вас слишком "везде")

Comment: @OliverPatterson Если язык допускает запятую после последнего элемента массива, то лучше её ставить - меньше шансов, что при последующем добавлении элемента в массив эту запятую таки забудут )

Comment: @OliverPatterson если интересно можно тут почитать https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Trailing_commas

Comment: @CrazyElf согласен с вами

Comment: С данным массивом наверняка for of был бы попроще

Comment: Быть может автор хотел именно `console.info` вместо `console.log` ? :)

Comment: @CrazyElf, возможно вы и правы.. Но я привык убирать, ибо это приводит к ошибке в JSON.

Comment: @OliverPatterson JSON этим бесит, нигде нет проблем с лишней запятой в конце, а там есть :)

Answer (score 0):

- Я бы назвал переменную `weekDays`, а то вы пишите недели, а храните дни. Просто для других это может быть путаницей, пока они не найдут объявление этой переменной
- Я бы рекомендовал привыкать использовать `const` вместо `let`, чтобы не было ненужного соблазна переопределять переменную
- Если надо просто прогуляться по значениям массива, то я бы использовал цикл `for of`

Код:

```js
const weekDays = [
  'Понедельник',
  'Вторник',
  'Среда',
  'Четверг',
  'Пятница',
  'Суббота',
  'Воскресенье'
];

for (const weekDay of weekDays) console.log(weekDay);
```

Answer (score 0):

Перебор всех элементов массива с помощью forEach

```
ler weeks = [
  'Понедельник',
  'Вторник',
  'Среда',
  'Четверг',
  'Пятница',
  'Суббота',
  'Воскресенье'
];
weeks.forEach(element => {
    console.log(element)
})
```